# Jquery Hide li on first of month

Tags: jquery

I'm a css person not a progammer so jquery's a bit beyond me so apologies if this is really simple but I cant get there. I've a UL with one li per month. I'd like a function to hide all li's based on the month. Ie, I want all li's to vanish once the month they represent has past, so that only the current and future months remain.

Seeing as there's one li per month and they're in order, it occured to me an easy way would be to get current month as a number -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 

var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMonth();
```

And compare n to the index of the li, and hide it if it is smaller. Something like this

```
var listItem = $( "li" );
alert( "Index: " + $( "li" ).index( listItem )  );

if (n > listItem) {
$('li).hide();
}
```

But I cant get it to work for each li - think I need to store them in an array?

Comment: typo or bug? `$('li).hide();` (Should have a closing quote.)

Comment: `$("li").each(function(idx, item){ item.toggle(idx < n); })` ?

Comment: @teran ooh! I like that one.  It needs item to be thrown in a jQuery object to work though.  `item` in this context is a simple node. https://jsfiddle.net/d87pmr1c/

Comment: @JosephMarikle it's also posible to use selector like `$("li:lt(2)").hide();`

Comment: @teran neat!  Why not post it as an answer.  I haven't used that selector before.  I'm sure others could benefit from it too.

Comment: @JosephMarikle done! :)

Answer (score 1):

ok, answer from comments. There are many ways to achieve desired result.

```
$(function(){
    var mIdx = new Date().getMonth();

    $("ul#months li").each(
           function(idx, item){ 
               $(item).toggle(idx >= mIdx); 
           });
}
```

you can iterate collection of `li` and hide required elements, use `toggle` to set `dsiplay` to `none`, or you can `remove()` elements, or `addClass("hidden")`, or `toggleClass("hidden", ...)` and so on..

or you can construct required selector and `hide\remove\toggle` elements:

```
$("li:lt(" + mIdx + ')').hide();
```

but, if you need to hide something on page load, imho, better do not render it at server side at all.

**update**:
added code snippet to demostrate:

```js
var mIdx = new Date().getMonth();
$("ul#months li:lt(" + mIdx + ')').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="months">
  <li>January</li>
  <li>February</li>
  <li>March</li>
  <li>April</li>
  <li>May</li>
  <li>June</li>
  <li>July</li>
  <li>August</li>
  <li>September</li>
  <li>October</li>
  <li>November</li>
  <li>December</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Like the simplicity of this, thanks. But when I try it, it loops through and hides all the li's regardess of their index value.

Comment: @GuillaumeRoberts I've added code snippet for example

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what exactly you are asking but I hope this is what you are looking  for....

```
<ul id="moths"> 
<li>Jan</li>
...... 
</li>Dec</li>
</li>

<script>
function hideCurrentMonth(selector){
   $(selector+' li').eq(new Date().getMonth()).prevAll().hide();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my own experience, it is better to relay on the list item value
rather than on the order of your list and indexes.
You didn't post exactly how your list items shows the dates, so I wrote and simple (and not really elegant) example that demonstrate how you can achieve this check by val and hide the date:

```
<body>
    <ul id="monthsList">
        <li>03</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
 var monthsElements = $("#monthsList").children();

var currMonth = "03"; // I saw that you already know how to use new Date() to get the current month, im just not sure
// how you represent your months in the html li's

for (var i = 0; i < monthsElements.length ; i++)
{   
var currMonthLi = monthsElements[i];

if ($(currMonthLi).text() == currMonth)
{
    $(currMonthLi).hide();
}

}
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, should have explained about the HTML - the li's contain lots of markup so I cant just use their value. I could assign them id's, or data index values.

Comment: Alright, so my solution should work I think if you adjust the "if" to check their id instead of text